# How to get object bound to DataGridRow in Xaml?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, viewmodel, wpfdatagrid

There is DataGrid with ItemsSource as ObservableCollection. ParticipantViewModel having property named ExpenseType, Currency etc. For some specific expense types participant can change currency and this can be determined from another property of ParticipantViewModel named IsCurrencyEnable. I bind IsCurrencyEnable with ComboBox IsEnabled property.

But it is searching for IsCurrencyEnable in the MainViewModel instead of ParticipantViewModel.

How can I bind IsEnabled property such a way that it get value from ParticipantViewModel?

Thanks.

Comment: Post the relevant code and XAML.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a datacontext issue.  You need to bind with the following

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ControlTypeThatBindsToParticipantViewModel}},Path=DataContext.IsCurrencyEnable}
```

ControlTypeThatBindsToParticipantViewModel THis is the type of control that is binding its datacontext to ParticipantViewModel, could be window, usercontrol, etc.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. The DataGrid ItemSource is of type ObservableCollection<ParticipantViewModel>(property of MainViewModel). And each row of DataGrid displays databind for properties of ParticipantViewModel so it's DataGridRow control bound to ParticipantViewModel. But when I use {Bind IsCurrencyEnable} it searches for  IsCurrencyEnable property in MainViewModel.

Comment: you really need to post the xaml code like HighCore suggested, otherwise we can't help. Did you try my solution?